# can't retrieve an updated boolean data or update it properly in realm database

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using realm database to save data. Though I have succeeded in saving String and int data, the problem is boolean. I use a checkbox and am trying to save a state of whether an item is checked or not but I can't do it even though I am doing the same way as I did for the String and int data. More specifically, I can save boolean data temporarily but I can't retrieve the data after I close the app. I confirmed the data is saved right after I checked and set default after it's closed by using a debugger. Anyone can tell me why this is happening?

Here's my code for the check box

```
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mWordData = mRealm.where(Word.class).equalTo("id", mWordId).findFirst(); //mWordId is sent from another activity by using intent and this mWordData works properly because it doesn't return null

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkButton:
            if (checked) {
                mRealm.beginTransaction();
                mWordData.setChecked(true);
                mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mWordData);
                mRealm.commitTransaction();
            } else {
                mRealm.beginTransaction();
                mWordData.setChecked(false);
                mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mWordData);
                mRealm.commitTransaction();
            }
            break;
    }
}

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      mRealm.close();
  }
```

Here's for the model class

```
@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private boolean checked;

public void setId(String sid) {
    id = Integer.parseInt(sid);
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where `mWordData` comes from and I don't know if it has a primary key

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Here's the id

Comment: @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    public void setId(String sid) {
        id = Integer.parseInt(sid);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

Comment: Here's mWordData

Comment: mWordData = mRealm.where(Word.class).equalTo("id", mWordId).findFirst();

Comment: hmm in that case it should just work

Comment: I've just found why, that is this app retrieves default csv data saved in realm data base when opened, which set all the data default when retrieved. Thanks.